# SQL: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, vba

I am writing a SQL statement through VBA. When typing in the product origin in a textbox, it will retrieve all product IDs from the same origin and their average price. Below is my SQL statement:

```
SQL = "SELECT PRO_ID, AVG(PRO_PRICE_ " & _
      "FROM PRODUCT " & _
      "GROUP BY PRO_ORIGIN = '" & Label1.Value & "'"
```

It gives me an error SQL: not a single-group group function. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Select pro_id , avg(pro_price_) from product where pro_origin = “put you label” Group by pro_id.   — Try using this and add those “” where ever required for concatenation

Comment: Do not munge query strings!  Learn to use parameters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PRO_ORIGIN` condition should be in a `WHERE` clause, and you should be grouping by `PRO_ID`:

```
SQL = "SELECT PRO_ID, AVG(PRO_PRICE) " & _
      "FROM PRODUCT " & _
      "WHERE PRO_ORIGIN = '" & Label1.Value & "' " & _
      "GROUP BY PRO_ID"
```

Also you have a typo, `AVG(PRO_PRICE_` should be `AVG(PRO_PRICE)`.

Comment: Why do I have to group by PRO_ID?

Comment: Because you want to get the average price for *each* product (PRO_ID)